# How to install circletype.js in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I would like to arch a text in a website. The easy and fast way to do it, it seems to be using circletype.js

http://circletype.labwire.ca/

What I have to write in functions.php to make it works?

I read it requires even lettering.js

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/#scripts

Comment: `code`wp_enqueue_script('theme-jquery-lettering', THEME_DIR_URI . '/includes/js/jquery.lettering.js', array('jquery') );